# Tables - 'Dotted square brackets' inside cells what are they? Causing alignment problems

Tags: microsoft-word, alignment

I can't figure this out. What are these dotted square brackets and how do I change their size etc.

I've had to insert new columns then re-enter text to get them the same width/alignment - if the width is different the rows do not align.

I tried format painter, goggling, paragraph setting, table layout alignment  etc but had no luck.

Could someone pls tell me how to modify these 'dotted brackets' - circled in attached image.

[image]

AJ

Ps. Notice the one at row 7 extends outside the table.

Comment: Looks like no one knows... Perhaps you can create sample file from your current one (by removing unneccessary parts and rewriting  remaining content), upload it somewhere and share a link so someone can get it and analyze.